# How to perform exhaustive state checking in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

Is it possible to check that each legal state in a model is reached?
And if it is possible, how should the property be written?

Consider the module below where a 24 hour clock is modulated.
I am able to check that `hour` is not in a illegal state, i.e. that its between 0 and 23.
But if I write a bad `Next` predicate e.g. `hour' = (hour + 1) % 23`, not all states is reached but the properties does not catch this error.

```
----------------------------- MODULE Clock -----------------------------
EXTENDS Naturals
VARIABLE hour

Init ==
    hour \in 0..23

Next == 
    hour' = (hour + 1) % 24

Spec == 
    /\ Init
    /\ [][Next]_hour

\* Properties
hourMinBound == [](hour >= 0)
hourMaxBound == [](hour <= 23)
=============================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ReachesAllStates == \A h \in 0..23: <>(hour = h)
```

This will check that it reaches each state at least once. To check that it continually reaches every state, you need

```
KeepsReachingAllStates == \A h \in 0..23: []<>(hour = h)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between the two?
How should it not keep reaching all states?

Comment: One says "eventually the hour will be `foo`", the second says "always eventually the hour will be `foo`". It takes some getting used to. A possible intuition is that for the first case, it's okay if the clock cycles twice and then breaks.

Comment: I have now tried both solutions, but I get an error with both.